# How do I set a variable to the text returned? - Applescript

Tags: applescript

How can I set a variable to the text returned?

text returned from:

```
display dialog "Type something" default answer "" buttons {"Done"} default button 1
```

Automatic code after that:

```
copy the result as list to {text_returned, button_pressed}
```

Variable code:

```
set thing to text returned of the result
```

Error Message:

**Script Error**

Can't get text returned of {"Done","kjhfsddfhksh"}.

I also tried other thing like that^, but they also didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You seem very close. This works for me:

```
display dialog "Foo?" default answer "Yes"
set theText to text returned of the result
```

If you're doing anything between the display dialog and accessing the result then the result may no longer be set.

Comment: Because of that, I like to: `set theResult to (display dialog "Foo?")`. Or sometimes `set theResult to the result`. Then rather than the ephemeral `result`, I can keep using `theResult` to get, say, the button value after I've gotten the text value.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got:

```
display dialog "Password" default answer ""
set w to text returned of the result
if w = "Password" then
    display notification w
end if
```